# Python - Trying to replace words in a list of strings but having problems with single letter words

Tags: python, list, replace, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings such as
`words = ['Twinkle Twinkle', 'How I wonder']`
I am trying to create a function that will find and replace words in the original list and I was able to do that except for when the user inputs single letter words such as 'I' or 'a' etc.

current function

```py
def sub(old: string, new: string, words: list):
    words[:] = [w.replace(old, new) for w in words]
```

if input for old = 'I'
and new = 'ASD'

**current output** = `['TwASDnkle TwASDnkle', 'How ASD wonder']`

**intended output** = `['Twinkle Twinkle', 'How ASD wonder']`

This is my first post here and I have only been learning python for a few months now so I would appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: Please reformat the code with the code block

Comment: Sorry, first ever post here. Changed the text to the code block format

Comment: I mean the function is giving the correct output. It IS replacing 'i' with 'ASD'. You have implemented no logic that `old` should be whole word and not any character in a word

Comment: can't reproduce your issue nor should it exist, if you use a capital _I_, then it should only replace the capital _I_ s, I get your intended output, also there is no point in using `words[:]`

Comment: Right. It doesn't even reproduce with capital `I`. The function works with the logic written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `str.replace` in a loop. This often doesn't do what is expected as it doesn't work on words but on all matches.

Instead, `split` the words, replace on match and `join`:

```
l = ['Twinkle Twinkle', 'How I wonder']

def sub(old: str, new: str, words: list):
    words[:] = [' '.join(new if w==old else w for w in x.split()) for x in words]
    
sub('I', 'ASD', l)
```

Output: `['Twinkle Twinkle', 'How ASD wonder']`

Or use a regex with word boundaries:

```
import re

def sub(old, new, words):
    words[:] = [re.sub(fr'\b{re.escape(old)}\b', new, w) for w in words]
    
l = ['Twinkle Twinkle', 'How I wonder']
sub('I', 'ASD', l)
# ['Twinkle Twinkle', 'How ASD wonder']
```

*NB. As @re-za pointed out, it might be a better practice to `return` a new list rather than mutating the input, just be aware of it*

Comment: I suggest returning a new list in the function instead of mutating the passed argument.

Comment: @re-za this was OP's intended behavior, I would agree otherwise. I added a note ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are replacing letters and not words. I recommend splitting sentences (strings) into words by splitting strings by the `' '` (space char).

```
output = []
```

I would first get each string from the list like this:

```
for string in words:
```

I would then split the strings into a list of words like this:

```
    temp_string = '' # a temp string we will use later to reconstruct the words
    for word in string.split(' '):
```

Then I would check to see if the word is the one we are looking for by comparing it to `old`, and replacing (if it matches) with `new`:

```
        if word == old: 
            temp_string += new + ' '
        else:
            temp_string += word + ' '
```

Now that we have each word reconstructed or replaced (if needed) back into a temp_string we can put all the temp_strings back into the array like this:

```
    output.append(temp_string[:-1]) # [:-1] means we omit the space at the end
```

It should finally look like this:

```
def sub(old: string, new: string, words: list):
    output = []
    for string in words:
        temp_string = '' # a temp string we will use later to reconstruct the words
        for word in string.split(' '):
            if word == old: 
                temp_string += new + ' '
            else:
                temp_string += word + ' '
        output.append(temp_string[:-1]) # [:-1] means we omit the space at the end
    return output
```